# W3Schools jQuery Quiz

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

There is a jQuery quiz posted on the W3Schools site here...

http://www.w3schools.com/quiztest/quiztest.asp?qtest=jQuery

Question #19 is as follows,

> Look at the following jQuery selector: $("div#intro .head").
>
> What does it select?
>
> A. The first element with id="head" inside any div element with class="intro"
>
> B. All elements with class="head" inside the first div element with id="intro"
>
> C. All div elements with id="intro" or class="head"

I got it correct by picking answer B.

My question has to do with the wording of answer B.

Shouldn't the word, "first", be removed from the answer?

> B. All elements with class="head" inside the div element with id="intro"

ID is defined as "a **unique** identifier to an element", so not really understanding why they would refer to the *"the **first** div element with id=intro"*

I don't believe that it's intentionally trying to be tricky as all the other questions in this quiz are very straightforward.

Thank-you for your thoughts.

---

**EDIT:**

I reported this error to W3Schools and directed them to this thread.

---

**EDIT #2:**

This is another question from the same quiz.

[Another questionable jQuery Quiz answer at W3Schools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711040/another-questionable-jquery-quiz-answer-at-w3schools)

Comment: Check out http://w3fools.com/. As a note for all readers who stumble here: Try to use jQuery's documentation (http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) and the Mozilla Javascript Docs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript) as @Andrew Whitaker explained in a sidenote on his answer. Way better information when it come from the creators.

Comment: @Dale, I've learned a lot since posting this question more than six months ago.  I rely on the official specs at the W3.org for HTML reference, and of course, the official jQuery site for jQuery reference.

Comment: I could tell that. I was just posting this as a comment under your question for those who just pass through and see it. Sorry if it made you feel I was trying to correct you. Good on you for using good documentation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are correct, the **first** language could (*should*) be removed from all choices.

According to the [HTML 4.01 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2):

> This attribute assigns a name to an
>   element. This name must be unique in a
>   document.

Additionally, according to the jQuery [documentation for the id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/):

> Selects a single element with the
>   given id attribute

Under the hood, the selector uses [`document.getElementById("...")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementByID). Interestingly, [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-getElBId) for this function states:

> Behavior is not defined if more than
>   one element has this ID.

So, assuming you do have two elements with the same `id`, results of the function are unpredictable and browser-specific.

**Sidenote**: W3Schools is not regarded as one of the best places to learn JavaScript / jQuery. A well-respected alternative for JavaScript is [MDC's JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide). For jQuery, check out the [tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials) page.

Comment: @Andrew: I actually learn most of my jQuery over at the jQuery site and come search here at StackOverflow when I get stuck.  I was mostly playing around with the quiz at W3School because I was investigating their "prerequisites" for jQuery Certification.  I don't consider myself to be a jQuery expert but I easily scored 95% (19/20) on their quiz.  Seeing the improper wording in that answer, I figured I'd confirm what I already suspected by posting here.  My opinions on these kinds of certifications are now shifting.

Comment: @Sparky672: Nice--You are correct in questioning certifications from sites like W3Schools. In my opinion, there isn't often much value in programming certifications (aside from learning), simply because languages change so quickly! Additionally, there are so many certifications out there, it's hard to know which to obtain. StackOverflow and the jQuery site are probably your best bets :)

Comment: @Sparky672: There are some interesting questions/answers related to certifications in that tag: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/certification?sort=votes&pagesize=50

Comment: @Andrew: thank-you for confirming my suspicions.  I posted another question only because now I'm doubting them more than I otherwise would have.    
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711040/another-questionable-jquery-quiz-answer-at-w3schools)

Comment: W3Schools sucks, it is good for learning basics, but at the end of the day it there to make money from its users, not like stack overflow.

Comment: Amen to W3Schools being a less-than-desirable resource. If you want to Google something, you can add "-w3schools" to your query to eliminate any matches on their site from your results. Maybe one day it won't be one of the top results for most queries.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the behavior of document.getElementById("...") is undefined if more than one element has this ID.

However, as the w3schools site consistently tries to point out, the behavior of jQuery in this situation is well-defined.  If more than one element has this ID, then the *first* one will be selected.

No one is condoning more than one element's having a particular ID; this is still against the rules.  However, unlike getElementById, jQuery has a specific reaction if this rule is broken.

Comment: In order for the wording of the quiz answer to make complete sense, the code of the hypothetical page would need to be non-compliant.