# How comes jQuery selector for "first element with id=foo"?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

While making a quick review on jQuery selectors, I came across [this page in w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp).

In the *Some More Examples* table, the second row, it says:

```
$("p#intro:first")  | Selects the first <p> element with id="intro"
```

It says: *the first element with id="intro"*. But AFAIK there can be only **one** element with a certain id in a **valid** HTML document.

The question is: is it *ever* allowed to have two (or more) elements with the same id in a valid HTML document, or this is a mistake in the tutorial? or even in jQuery?!

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Oh boy, here come the comments about w3schools. 3...2...1...

Comment: Related... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710350/w3schools-jquery-quiz/5710362#5710362

Comment: And to answer your question, no. It's never valid to re-use IDs.

Comment: yeah, this is just a case of w3schools being a mediocre resource, at best. Tehnically true, the selector will do what they say it will do, but as you pointed out, it's a bad example because IDs are supposed to be unique anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it ever allowed to have two (or more) elements with the same id in a valid HTML document,

No

> or this is a mistake in the tutorial?

Sort of.

Since you are allowed only one element with a given id, explicitly requesting the first one is redundant … in good documents.

There might be some browsers which will error recover in such a way so as to provide you with multiple results (especially if jQuery passes things on to `querySelectorAll` rather than `getElementById`) when you have multiple elements with the same id (in an invalid document) and this might filter out the subsequent ones … but this isn't something you should be doing in your own documents. It might be justifiable if you are writing JS to run over third party code in a known subset of browsers which you know error recover in that way.

Comment: `$('[id="myID"]')` *can* return multiple elements, but that's cheating :-P